# Django fails to catch/handle csrf token

Tags: python, django, csrf, django-allauth

I have a page that worked before, unfortunately I don't have a recent backup so I can go back to the most recently working version of the page.

What I have is a page that is using allauth to handle pages to create and login users. However, now when I fill out the form to register or login a user, I get a `403 error`, saying `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted`.

I have checked the cookies of the page, and there is a `csrf token` present. I tried removing that and reloading the page. THe cookie was recreated again, but still the same error. The same error also for login into the `admin` page, and I can only assume for any other page with a `form`.

I have included `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` in my settings file, so I am at a loss as to what is causing this error.

My `settings.py`

```
import os, djcelery
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = censored...
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0', '127.0.0.1', 'localhost']

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'interface',
    'chemrun',
    'kombu.transport.django',
    'chemicalizer.tasks',
    'json',
    'django_nvd3',
    'djangobower',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'djangosecure',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'djangosecure.middleware.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)   

ROOT_URLCONF = 'chemicalizer.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['interface'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
            'django.template.context_processors.static',
            'django.template.context_processors.tz',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
    },
]
```

Comment: Can you add template/views in which this happens?

Comment: I use allauth, so it is the standard template and view for it. I haven't changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code is not sending the CSRF token back. It needs to be added to header.

Comment: How would I do that? I am pretty new still with Django so a detailed description is very helpful :)

Comment: CSRF is a very simple thing. Server sends a token to it's client, and on the next request client sends it's back. CSRF token is sent via page header. If your server complains about CSRF token, this means it's eather missing (not sent), or differs (perhaps server configuration issues).

Comment: Since I can see the cookie in my browser, I take it that is enough to show it is sent, but somehow the server does not recognise it, due to configuration issues. Do you have an idea as to what issues I might look for?

Comment: This cookie needs to be sent back on the next request as `X-CSRFToken` header. You can check it's presence in *Chrome -> Developer Tools -> Network -> File -> Headers*. Please note, this cookie changes with every response from the server. Have you checked this doc? It's pretty informative: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/

Comment: It looked through the header and `X-Frame-Options` is set to `DENY` for some reason. Might that cause the problem? I assume it should be set to `SAMEORIGIN` but I don't know where that can/should be done.
I did read through the page, but it appears a bit too technical for me. At least I can't find what is my mistake is, as I feel I have done things exactly like they list it....which I obviously can't have or have at least something additional that screw things up.

Comment: Sorry, but `X-Frame-Options` is something completely different. It's not enough information to nail down the root cause. I suggest you to analyze the logs, and/or remove CSRF completely, and try to add it back step by step.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Many thanks for the help! I will try reading up more on csrf as well